# Intellij Idea does not hit breakpoints with custom webpack config of React JS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, intellij-idea

What steps will reproduce the issue?

1. Create webpack config file for react js project. Set some breakpoints
2. npm start to start the web app
3. Press debug icon to start the Javascript Debug.

What is the expected result?

Breakpoints need to be hit

What happens instead?

Breakpoints are missed.

Additionaly, I can see that breakpoints set in chrome dev toolkit open up webpack:// window in IDea for the same breakpoint as in the chrome source code tab. However, I would like to hit the breakpoints in Idea itself without having to set them in Chrome. ALso line numbers are different in Idea breakpoint and Chrome triggered breakpoints. So clearly seems like Source Map related issue. I am unsure which config Idea is looking for inside my custom webpack config? Do I need to specify sourcemaps somehow? or is there somethign else I am missing?

I have sample webpack being used below

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  devtool: "source-map",
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: './fonts/[name][ext]',
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', ".tsx"]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8089,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "public/index.html",
    hash: true, // cache busting
    filename: '../build/index.html'
  })]
}
```

Comment: `devtool: "source-map"` should be fine, can be an issue with specific loaders. Do you have a sample project you can share that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by adding     "sourceMap": true in my tsconfig.json. I am not sure why the question was downvoted when there are so many posts for different IDEs ( including VS code ) that have this issue. Including this one on IntelliJ idea site which had no resolution documented from the responders. Clearly, it is an issue where IntelliJ silently fails or ignores breakpoints without adding sourcemap in tsconfig.json.

Comment: There is no mention of this requirement anywhere in the documentation related to webpack configs or react for that matter that I could easily find. Here are the links for those who are interested in fixing the issue or docs from the product team https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009445219-SourceMaps-and-JS-Debug-Acting-Strange?page=1#community_comment_13213076593554

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding "sourceMap": true in my tsconfig.json. There is no mention of this requirement anywhere in the documentation related to webpack configs or react for that matter that I could easily find. Here are the links for those who are interested in fixing the issue or docs from the product team https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-webpack.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-typescript-to-javascript.html#ts_compiler_compile_code